# Do I need to export helper functions in the following javascript code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry if this is a very obvious thing but this is my first assignment in `javascript` dealing with exporting modules in `node.js`.

I have two files: 1) `ADT.js` and 2) `main.js`.
I am trying to export some of the functions of `ADT.js` to `main.js`

Here is code in `ADT.js`:

```
module.exports = {};
var exports = module.exports;

var wordCount = function(text) {

    var data = readFile(text);

    if(checkEmptyFile(data)){
        return null;
    } else {
        // do something
    }
};

//==================== Helper Functions ==================================
function readFile (file){

    var fs = require('fs');
    var data = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");

    return data; 
}

function checkEmptyFile(data){

    if(data.replace(/\s+/, '') === ''){

        return true;
    }
}

/** adding the functions to the exports module */
exports.wordCount = wordCount;
```

Code in `main.js`:

```
 /** Importing the data_structures.js module  */
var adt = require("./ADT");

var main = function(...){

    if (firstWord === ""){
        console.log(...);
    } else {
        makePoem(...);

        if(printResult === true){
            console.log("Word Count: "+
                    JSON.stringify(adt.wordCount(fileName)));
            console.log("");
        }            
    }        
};

var makePoem = function(...){

    ...;        
};
```

Do I need to export the helper functions too? I am not going to explicitly use the helper functions anywhere in the `main.js`.

Comment: Does this code run? If it does, you should be okay, no need to export.

Comment: Why do you ask? You only have to export what other modules should be able to use / call.

Comment: You only need to export functions that will be directly called. If you aren't going to directly call it, then there is no need to export it. Node will maintain context and access to the functions without you needing to export them.

Comment: I still have quite a bit to write in most of the functions. Not in a position to check the code at the moment. Will be able to test this by tomorrow.

Comment: Looks good to me, if you're confused with the whole concept of exports, think of it as exposing components of your library as a public interface for others to use.  Anything not added to `exports` is internal, so it can be invoked by the public method, but not directly by a caller.

Comment: Absolutely , for your unit tests :)

Comment: Thanks frosty, Alex and dm03514. Yes I am a bit confused with how modules work. Thanks for your helpful responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of exporting a function from a module is purely to make it available for other modules to use.  If the function is only used within the current module and it is your intent to keep it that way, then there is no reason to export it.

You can think of functions that are defined within a module, but not exported as "local" functions that are private to the module.  You can use them anywhere within the module in which they are defined, but they cannot be called from other modules.  The act of exporting them (assigning them as a property of `module.exports`) makes them callable from the outside world.